# HPA is unable to fetch custom metrics from prometheus adapter

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, autoscaling

I have configured Prometheus-adapter to fetch custom metrics from Prometheus.
When I execute the command:
`kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`

Following is the result.

```
 {
      "name": "namespaces/envoy_http_ingress_http_downstream_cx_http1",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "namespaces/envoy_cluster_xds_cluster_upstream_cx_rx_bytes",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": false,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "jobs.batch/statsd_exporter_lines",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pods/fs_writes_merged",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "MetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
```

My HPA configuration is as follows:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: scale
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: billing-app
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  # targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
  metrics:
    - type: External
      external:
        metricName: fs_writes_merged
        targetValue: 100
```

Hpa results in unknown. Not sure why it is not able to fetch metrics.

Hpa must be able to read the custom metrics.

Comment: Have you followed [this guide](https://itnext.io/horizontal-pod-autoscale-with-custom-metrics-8cb13e9d475)?

Comment: Yes i followed.

Comment: If you followed the mentioned guide, you should have `type: Pod` and not `type: External` as metrics type in you HPA definition (and below that the key was `pods` not `external`). Maybe try changing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer

Since your HPA configuration declares the metric as `type: External`, the HPA tries to fetch it from the External Metrics API (`/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io`), but the Prometheus Adapter exposes it on the Custom metrics API (`/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io`).

Since your metric comes from the Pods of the Deployment that you're trying to autoscale, you should use the `Pods` metric type. So, change your HPA configuration to:

```
  # ...
  metrics:
    - type: Pods
      pods:
        metricName: fs_writes_merged
        targetValue: 100
```

## Background

You can see all the available HPA metric types and their usages here:

```
kubectl explain --api-version=autoscaling/v2beta1 hpa.spec.metrics
```

There are four metric types, and they map to the various metric APIs as follows:

- `Resource`: Resource Metrics API (`/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`)
- `Pods`: Custom Metrics API (`/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`)
- `Object`: Custom Metrics API (`/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`)
- `External`: External Metrics API (`/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`)

See [HPA docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-metrics-apis), and design documents for [Resource Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md), [Custom Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/custom-metrics-api.md), and [External Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/external-metrics-api.md).